# bugs decoding image with the flutter Image lib

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a project where I send i send jpeg image over MQTT broker to a flutter app, am trying to decode the image using the flutter image lib but its not working for this is the code snippet below:

````
``` import 'package:image/image.dart' as img; ```
````

````
      client.updates?.listen(
        (List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
          var recMess = c[0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
          img.Image? jpegImage =
              img.decodeJpg(recMess.payload.message.first as Uint8List);
          print("====${jpegImage!.width}======${jpegImage!.height}");

          
        },
      );
    } 

this is the error i am getting: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List' in type cast```
````

Comment: not sure how to fix but you need to cast Uint8List as an Integer type perhaps?

Comment: `message` is a `Uint8Buffer` - see https://pub.dev/documentation/mqtt_client/latest/mqtt_client/MqttPublishPayload/message.html so use `recMess.payload.message.buffer.asUint8List()` Note that you may need to supply offset and length if the underlying buffer's are non-zero.

Comment: alright ill be trying it, hopefully i can get it to work

Comment: `if (!isListening) {
      client.updates?.listen(
        (List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
          var recMess = c[0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
          img.Image? jpegImage =
              img.decodeJpg(recMess.payload.message.buffer.asUint8List());
          print("====${jpegImage!.width}======${jpegImage!.height}");

      
        },
      );
    }
  }`

it kind work but another error came up :
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ImageException: Only single frame JPEGs supported